# Why won't my Svelte dropdown close when the dropdown is open, but I click on the Dropdown Box?

Tags: html, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

**What Works**

Hi, I have an issue with my custom `HTML` dropdown made in Svelte. I'm a React engineer and new to svelte due to this company code that this small portion was written in just because previous from previous devs.

The initial click to open, `handleSelection`, and `clickOutside`, work.

**What Doesn't Work**

When the dropdown is open, the user should be able to click the dropdown box (`class="select"`) and the dropdown should close. It doesn't close. Thanks in advance!

**inputSelect.svelte**

```html
<svelte:options tag="input-select" />

<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import { get_current_component } from "svelte/internal";
  import Button from "./button.svelte";

  export let options = [];
  let selectedOption = null;
  let isOpen = false;
  let parent: HTMLElement;

  const component = get_current_component();

  function openDropdown(event: MouseEvent): void {
    console.log("openDropdown");
    isOpen = !isOpen;
    console.log("");
  }

  function handleSelection(value: string, event: Event): void {
    console.log("HANDLE SELECTION");
    selectedOption = value;

    component?.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent("selectedOptionChanged", { detail: value })
    );

    console.log("HANDLE SELECTION");
    console.log("");
  }

  function clickOutside(node: HTMLElement) {
    const handleClick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      if (
        node &&
        !node.contains(event.target as Node) &&
        isOpen === true
      ) {
        console.log("CLICK OUTSIDE");
        isOpen = false;
        console.log("");
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick, true);

    return {
      destroy() {
        document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick, true);
      },
    };
  }

  onMount(() => {
    clickOutside(parent);
  });
</script>

<div>
  <div
    class="custom-select"
    style="border-color: {isOpen ? '#1677ff' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)'};"
  >
    <label
      for="entity-type"
      style="display: block; font-weight: 1000; margin-bottom: 4px;"
    >
      Entity Type {isOpen}
    </label>

    <div>
      <div
        class="select"
        class:select-arrow-active={isOpen}
        on:click={openDropdown}
        use:clickOutside
        bind:this={parent}
      >
        {#if selectedOption === null}
          <div>Select</div>
        {:else}
          <div>
            {options.find(
              (option) => option.value === selectedOption
            )?.label}
          </div>
        {/if}

        <div
          class="select-items"
          style={isOpen ? "display: block;" : "display: none;"}
        >
          {#each options as option (option.value)}
            <div
              on:click={(event) => {
                handleSelection(option.value, event);
                event.stopPropagation();
              }}
            >
              {option.label}
            </div>
          {/each}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style lang="scss">
    .custom-select {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;

        .select {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 8px 16px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            cursor: pointer;
            user-select: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            position: relative;

            &:after {
                content: "";
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 4px 4px 0 4px;
                border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) transparent transparent
                    transparent;
                position: relative;
                transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-180deg);
                margin-left: 8px;
                transition: transform 0.3s ease;
            }

            &.select-arrow-active::after,
            &.select-arrow-active::before {
                transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
            }
        }

        .select-items {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
            border-radius: 4px;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            z-index: 100;
        }

        .select-items div:hover {
            background-color: #bae0ff;
            color: #222222;
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .select-items div {
            padding: 8px 15px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .select-items div:first-child {
            border-top-left-radius: 4px;
            border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        }

        .select-items div:last-child {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        }

        .select-items div:first-child:hover {
            border-top-left-radius: 4px;
            border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        }

        .select-items div:last-child:hover {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

**What Logs To The Console**

1. Initial Click to open dropdown

`openDropdown`

2. Dropdown is open, now I click the select box.

```
CLICK OUTSIDE

openDropdown
```

Comment: This code is inaccessible and uses internal code it neither should be using, nor needs. The whole thing should be rewritten, or better yet: Just use a `<select>`.

Comment: I need custom HTML css. Essentially, I have to continue the antd (React library) design in custom HTML for Svelte

Comment: Then you should be prepared to do [all the work that is necessary](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/) to make one that is not complete trash.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem is that `openDropdown()` is called also when you click "outside". I imagine an easy fix is to call `event.stopPropagation()` in `handleClick()` (inside the `if`).